# SLDS Example required

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I am a newbie into lightning and want a good example to understand lightning. 
Can someone post **good example or use case** . I have already tried application and component events.

What I wish to learn is a good example which contain some live project.

Also I don't know how to use SLDS . **Can anyone tell how to use slds** with proper example with good look and feel of the example shared at https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/? The SLDS documentation is quite thorough. This question is not about specific implementation details, and "please give an example of X" questions are almost universally off topic on Stack Exchange sites. If you haven't already, please take a look at the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: I have written some texts about starting with Lightning basics. Take a look at https://medium.com/@renatoliveira/lightning-components-nesting-and-events-d63947681741, https://medium.com/@renatoliveira/lightning-components-handling-apex-errors-98510695cb42 and https://medium.com/@renatoliveira/user-activation-example-c52833767653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try trailhead modules dedicated to Lightning and slds ? They are pretty good for newcomers.

- [Lightning Design System](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system)
- [Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics)